# Encontrar expoente da equação que se ajusta aos dados, R

Tags: r

Gostaria de saber como fazer para ajustar essa equação/modelo abaixo aos meus dados observados(que são simples) de forma a encontra o expoente `p` desse modelo

```
y~x^(-p)
```

Meus dados são:

```
y=c(1.1178329,1.0871448,1.0897010,1.0759255,1.0535190,0.8725332)
x=c(6,5,4,3,2,1)
```

Eu tentei o seguinte modelo, mas os valores não se alteram e as iterações não prosseguem.

```
library(minpack.lm)
mod <- nlsLM( y ~ x^(-p),
 start = c(p = 0.01) , 
trace = TRUE, lower=c(0.01) , upper=c(1))
```

iterações...

```
It.    0, RSS =  0.0671647, Par. =       0.01
It.    1, RSS =  0.0671647, Par. =       0.01
```

Agradeço a todos a quem puderem me ajudar com essa questão.

Answer (score 3):

Não há problema nenhum com este ajuste ou código. Veja o que acontece quando altero o chute inicial para `0.9`:

```
y=c(1.1178329,1.0871448,1.0897010,1.0759255,1.0535190,0.8725332)
x=c(6,5,4,3,2,1)

library(minpack.lm)
mod1 <- nlsLM( y ~ x^(-p),
  start = list(p = 0.9) , 
  trace = TRUE, lower=0.1, upper=1)
It.    0, RSS =    2.99354, Par. =        0.9
It.    1, RSS =   0.246237, Par. =        0.1
It.    2, RSS =   0.246237, Par. =        0.1
```

Ocorrem mais iterações, como esperado. Se eu mantenho o valor inicial fixo e reduzo o limite inferior do grid de procura para `0.00001`, veja o que ocorre:

```
mod2 <- nlsLM( y ~ x^(-p),
              start = list(p = 0.1) , 
              trace = TRUE, lower=0.00001, upper=1)
It.    0, RSS =   0.246237, Par. =        0.1
It.    1, RSS =  0.0544138, Par. =      1e-05
It.    2, RSS =  0.0544138, Par. =      1e-05
```

Aparentemente, o valor ideal de `p` para este conjunto de dados é bastante próximo de 0. Note que inclusive o valor de RSS ([Residual Sum of Squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residual_sum_of_squares)) reduz de `mod1` para `mod2`, indicando que o segundo ajuste ficou melhor do que o primeiro.

Em resumo, não há nada errado com o código. Ele simplesmente está convergindo rápido demais.

Pode ser, ainda, que o valor de `p` não seja positivo. Pode ser que o valor de `p` que melhor se ajuste aos dados não pertença ao intervalo determinado pelo teu ajuste inicial, que está entre 0.1 e 1. Se isto for verdade, o valor de `p` vai convergir para algo na fronteira do intervalo definido na chamada da função. Tu chegou a pensar nesta hipótese?

Veja o código abaixo, por exemplo:

```
mod3 <- nlsLM( y ~ x^(-p),
              start = list(p = 0.1) , 
              trace = TRUE, lower=-1, upper=1)
It.    0, RSS =   0.246237, Par. =        0.1
It.    1, RSS =  0.0218977, Par. = -0.0816128
It.    2, RSS =  0.0166599, Par. = -0.0607616
It.    3, RSS =  0.0166587, Par. = -0.0604426
It.    4, RSS =  0.0166587, Par. = -0.0604428
```

`mod3` resultou no menor RSS de todos. Inclusive, tem mais cara de ajuste, pois levou mais tempo para chegar numa resposta, com mais interações e uma convergência mais suave no valor do parâmetro.

Answer (score 1):

Eu resolveria usando a função `optim` que serve para fazer otimizações arbitrárias, data uma função de perda com relação a alguns parâmetros.

Aqui vai um exemplo:

```
y=c(1.1178329,1.0871448,1.0897010,1.0759255,1.0535190,0.8725332)
x=c(6,5,4,3,2,1)

opt <- optim(runif(1), function(p){
  sum((y - x^(-p))^2)
}, method = "L-BFGS-B")

p <- opt$par
```

A função `optim` recebeu três parâmetros:

- O valor inicial do `p`
- A função de perda. No caso estamos minizando a soma dos quadrados dos resíduos desse modelo.
- O método de otimização.

O valor final foi de `-0.06044205`. Você pdoe fazer um gráfico da curva ajustada assim:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
data_frame(x = seq(1, 10, length.out = 100), y = x^(-p)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_line(colour = "blue")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A vantagem dessa abordagem é que você pode usar diferentes funções de perda e relações entre as variáveis. Também é fácil de incluir regularizações e etc.

Comment: Particularmente, também prefiro a `optim`. Acho ela bem mais geral, servindo pra praticamente qualquer caso que desejemos. Só acho ela menos amigável pra quem não tem um background estatístico ou matemático mais forte, mas entendo o teu ponto.

Comment: @MarcusNunes Sim, é mais complicado mesmo. Principalmente para fazer inferência... Do jeito que eu fiz, não tem nenhum intervalo de confiança ou teste de hipótese implementado! Não conheço o `minpack.lm`, mas acredito que ele deve ter esse tipo de coisa.

Answer (score 1):

Ou estou completamente errado ou `lm` chega para determinar `p`.

y ~ x^-p  <=> y ~ e^-p*log(x) <=> log(y) ~ -p*log(x)

Então ajustamos este último modelo linear.

```
fit <- lm(log(y) ~ 0 + log(x))
coef(fit)

p <- -coef(fit)
p
     log(x) 
-0.06054118

plot(x, y, log = "xy")
abline(fit)
```

Comment: Você tem que tirar o intercepto da regressão: `fit <- lm(log(y) ~ 0 + log(x))`, aí acho que fica equivalente. Acho que tem que tomar cuidado com os testes de hipóteses também. Aquele p-valor não é válido quando vc faz desse jeito.

Comment: @DanielFalbel Certo quanto ao intercepto da regressão, desculpe a pressa. Vou editar a resposta com essa modificação. Quanto ao p-valor, não concordo. A única coisa que interessa é saber se o coeficiente é ou não é significativo, o p-valor pode e deverá variar.

Comment: Sim, mas ele assume que log(y) tem distribuição normal que pode não ser o objetivo!

Comment: @DanielFalbel No modelo linear o que se assume que tem distribuição normal são os resíduos, não a resposta. É claro que será necessário ver os resíduos, com, por exemplo, um histograma.

Comment: é equivalente a resposta ou os residuos... se y = a + bx + e, com e normal(0, sigma) entao y ~normal(a + bx, sigma)...

Comment: @DanielFalbel Graficamente não vejo problema com o modelo linear. Há um outlier e nada mais. Vou voltar a editar a resposta, com as instrucões gráficas.